# Unique name for image before saving PHP

Tags: php, mysql

How do you set a unique name for the image? I'm trying to use `tempnam()` but it always saves the URL and the file as `.tpm`. Here is my code:

```
$file = $_FILES['file'];

$name = $file['name'];

$tname = tempnam("imagenes/", $name);

$path = "imagenes/" . basename($tname);
if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $path)) {
    // Move succeed.
} else {
    // Move failed. Possible duplicate?
}

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `productos` (`img`) VALUES ('".$path."')");
// ...
```

Also how do I check (for security) if the image has been really posted? Like *mime type* or something like that.

UPDATE:

I just fix unique name using

```
$tname =  uniqid().$name;
```

Comment: It's impossible to specify an extension using `tempnam()`. Unfortunately this is the truth

Comment: so , how can i set a unique name without that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check for valid image and filesize,

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| 
($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
||
($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
||
($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&&
($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 10485760)&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))                {

    //DO
}
```

For unique image, i suggest you to store images in new table and append imade id as file name!

Comment: but somebody told me it was very easy to "fake" an extension, so thats why i need to check the "mime type" i think?, is it true? SORRY I DIDNT SEE THE TYPE PART

Comment: Do you know why do i get.. Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in

Comment: @DreaminMediaQueretaro Note: While it's easy to fake the extension, it's easy to fake the mime-type as well. You cannot rely on this information when it comes to security checks. Just handle those files as *untrusted* data

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to specify an extension using `tempnam()`. Unfortunately this is the truth.

While the problem you described sounds like an easy to resolve task, it's problematic to avoid possible race conditions (without using `tempnam()`). And although it is unlikely that they appear, the possibility remains.

If you are sure that only PHP works in that directory, you could implement a `flock()` based mechanism to ensure that a file will have be created only once.

If you don't care too much about that possible, but very unlikely, race conditions, I would advice you too use something like this:

```
$filename = 'images/' . uniqid() . '.jpg';
```

Comment: yep , i just see your answer but yes, searching i found a similar question solver using uniqid() .  , but thanks really , your so kind for explanation, i really love to learn the WHY